# Start-Process powershell with spaces

Tags: powershell, mysql, start-process

I have been at this for a long while now, getting to the point where I'm very frustrated. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I need to run mysqldump, for 6 specific databases.
I need each spawn to run after the last has finished. It should not run all the commands at the same time. It needs to wait.

I've tried this:

```
$dump = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe"
$args = @('-u','databaseUser','-pMySuperAwesomePasswordHere','--single-transaction','--log-error=c:\backups\mysqldump_error.log',"$database > $backupFilePath\$database.sql")
Start-Process $dump $args -Wait
```

I've tried this:

```
$cmd = $backupCmd + $database + " > " + "$backupFilePath\$database.sql"
Write-Host $cmd
invoke-expression $cmd | out-null
```

How do I execute a command, especially one with redirecting the output to a file on the filesystem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection is a *shell* feature. `Start-Process` will dutifully include the last argument with the database name and the `>` in the actual argument passed to `mysqldump` which in turn has no idea what to do with the `>` at all.

You probably want something like

```
$args = '-u','databaseUser','-pMySuperAwesomePasswordHere','--single-transaction','--log-error=c:\backups\mysqldump_error.log',"$database"
& "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" @args | Out-File $backupFilePath\$database.sql
```

Since `mysqldump` is a console application it will wait anyway until it's done before continuing with the script.

Comment: A useful walk-through on handling external commands can be found here: http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Comment: @andyb: `--%` is handy; didn't know that yet.

Answer (score 0):

`| Out-File` wasn't working for me. I had to use the Parameter `-RedirectStandardOutput $PATH_TO_FILE` instead. HTH.